# How do you draw curved path, similar to the ones they show on treasure hunt maps, in iOS applications

Tags: ios

How do you draw a curved path (similar to the one showed below) that passes through a set of points in an iOS app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`UIBazierPath`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html

You create it, add your points to create the curve, set the required line dash, then use `- (void)stroke` to draw it.

Comment: @user462455 If my answer was sufficient for your needs, could you please accept it? Thanks